Firefox Graphics Issue
I recently installed Xubuntu 22.04 on a new PC Build. The PC is using the onboard GPU from an AMD 7900 X3D CPU. Everything displays correctly on the system, except for Firefox (see pic). Even though you can't see the window, the program is responsive.  I am able to navigate to google.com, and close down the application correctly.

I tried making changes to the Window Manager settings, Display, and XFCE settings but with no success.
I also erased the disk and installed ubuntu 23.10 Desktop on the PC, but that suffers from the same issue.
Does anyone know what could be causing it, and how I can fix it?
-Robert

Have you try to resize the window of Firefox?

I removed your tagging of the title with "SOLVED".  Accepting the answer automatically marks the issue as resolved.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

The problem ended up being with the version of firefox that was bundled with snap.  Removing firefox and downloading/using it directly from Mozilla's website resolved the problem.
# snap list && snap remove firefox

